# rails where.not -- how to do it this way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to return all of the profiles found except for one, the one of the current user. I was thinking of doing this from the model.

```
self.order('random()')
  .where(:blahblah => blah)
```

So everything is working up until here
I added this part, and it doesn't work

```
  .not(:email => "blah@blah.com")
```

And I am not sure why. The documentation shows queries that are like where.why(blah) and nothing like what I am doing. I am not sure where else to look. Thanks.

---

Getin NoMethodError

undefined method `not' for #

Comment: show the output of `to_sql` of your query

Comment: `self.order('random()').where(:blahblah => blah).not(:email => "blah@blah.com").to_sql`

Comment: Oh. I am not even able to get that far because of the error being thrown? Unless I should try that in the console. ?

Comment: Try `where.not(email: 'blah@blah.com')`

Comment: It worked. AGHHHHH. THANK YOU. why tho. ahh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on which rails version you are on,

if rails 3

`self.order('random()').where('email != ?', "blah@blah.com")`

if rails 4

`self.order('random()').where.not(email: "blah@blah.com")`